# What is this quasi-realistic, cartoon-style artwork used in this Jungle Cruise poster called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

[image: A version of the Jungle Cruise movie poster]

The people and items in the image have a distinct outline traced on their edges just like the average cartoon, yet their facial details aren't flattened out like those either. Their colors also involve a gradient between tones, which is typically also not employed with regular cartoons. What is this type of artwork called, and are there any good tutorials online on how to achieve this result?

Star Wars also had similar artwork, but their posters were traditional paintings photographed after, if I'm not grievously (heh) mistaken. Not entirely sure if it's the same method used with Jungle Cruise, though.

I'm hoping kind souls could help this newbie out. Thanks and appreciate any help and point me to any relevant tutorial sites.

Comment: I think it's simply photo-realistic illustration. Not every little technique or brush stroke use has a specific name.

Comment: Photo-realistic illustration, got it. Thank you, didn't know this before.

Comment: It's probably not an illustration. 

I think it is a photography collage with a light cartoonish filter added.

But yes if it were painted it would be called "Photo-realistic illustration"